# What are the boundary condition to simulate flow through vent mast?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, compressed-gases, compressible-flow

Dear all,

I am currently working on modeling compressible flows that occur when hydrogen needs to be evacuated (for purging, in case of fire, etc.).

I am endeavoring to determine the appropriate boundary conditions and algorithm for the issue depicted in the diagram below: [image]

In this diagram, P1 represents the known static pressure. The purge valve is treated as an orifice with a known cross-sectional area (s). P2 indicates the downstream valve pressure, while P3 represents the exit static pressure. The flow is vented into the atmosphere.
My initial approach is as follows:

1. Utilize P1 to determine the mass flow rate, considering that the flow is choked at the orifice.
2. Use the determined mass flow rate to calculate the exit pressure, considering that the flow is choked at the exit
3. Verify that the choked flow criteria are met (P3 > 2 * Patm).
4. Employ the Fanno flow equations for end choked conditions to determine P2.
5. Confirm that the choked flow criteria are satisfied (P1 > 2 * P2).

What are your thoughts on the proposed boundary conditions and algorithm? Have I made any obvious errors in reasoning?

Thanks for your time.